# How to create a test case on component with behavioursubject

Tags: angular

I have a component. inside ngOnInIt(), I am calling my service which is having a variable as behaviourSubject(null).
I want to create a test case for ngOnInIt() with mocking the behaviourSubject.
Can any one help me how to create it.

eg:
in service : suppose service name is DataService.cs

```
test=new BehaviorSubject(null);
public getData(){
   if(caseId){
      let data=Object.assign({},this.cachedData);
      this.test.next(data);
   }
}
```

in component: I have injected my service in constructor

```
constructor(dataService:new DataService()){}

ngOnInIt(){
  this.dataService.getData();
  this.dataService.text.subscribe({
       next:(//somevariable)=>
            {//code}
  });
}
```

Comment: It's about a time to choose the answer (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spec file

```
let fixture: ComponentFixture<YourComponent>;
let service: DataService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       // your configuration here
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
    service = TestBed.inject(DataService);
    
  });

it('test title', async () => {
   const spy = // spy on whatever you are testing inside `subscribe` method
   
   fixture.detectChanges(); // the first call to `detectChanges` triggers `ngOnInit`
   await fixture.whenStable(); // wait for all the subscriptions and promises to trigger the attached handlers

   expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['whatever you expect it to be called with'])
})
```

btw take care of memory leaks - unsubscribe the subscription.